# How to substring Html String in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

How is it possible to `substring` text containing `html` tags inside it with `jsp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys who is looking for the solution, first make sure you create any `helper class` that truncates `html coded string` without removing html codes. And you will need to create custom `taglib` to pass `jsp` value to `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

Using JSTL you can do it

${fn:substring(string1, 5, 15)}

[Here is the complete example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_substring.htm)

Comment: My text contains html tags so if i make like that it will break the html construction, so this is not solution.